# /etc/hosts alias or multiple record

Tags: linux, networking, hosts

I want to know what is different between this two configuration :
First :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost my-hostname
192.168.10.12   host-a a.com
```

Second :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost my-hostname
192.168.10.12   host-a 
192.168.10.12   a.com
```

What happened if i do not use aliases ?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller do you mean ping response ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `/etc/hosts` file these two alternatives are equivalent when resolving an address for a name. In both cases the names `host-a` and `a.com` will be resolved as the name `host-a` with address 192.168.10.12.

For a reverse lookup of name from IP address the two alternatives are slightly different. Both will return `host-a` as the canonical name. The first will include `a.com` as an alias.

You will get the first line of the file that matches, and the first text entry on that line is the canonical name.

Test framework (modify as necessary to test various scenarios):

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper(gethostbyname("a.com"))'

perl -MData::Dumper -e 'print Dumper(gethostbyaddr(pack("C4", 192, 168, 10, 12), 0))'
```

Personally, I try to avoid using `/etc/hosts`, preferring to use DNS. However there are some cases where it can be useful and in these situations I always put the FQDN first on a line and its alias(es) afterwards. I do the same by line in the file for actual machine name and its services.

Example, where `eleven` is the server's name and it provides the `web` and `ftp` services:

```
192.168.10.11 eleven.contoso.com eleven
192.168.10.11 web.contoso.com web
192.168.10.11 ftp.contoso.com ftp
```

Comment: Is reverse lookup of 192.168.10.12 guaranteed to return “host-a” in both formats?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I believe so

Comment: @ChrisDavies yes, pondering glibc's `compat-gethnamaddr.c` yields the same conclusion.